# Why is websocket slow when sending virtually no data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, websocket

I am running a multiplayer game with a node.js backend that sends messages 30 times per second. However, during testing I noticed that

```
let payload = new Float32Array(new ArrayBuffer(0));
console.time();
this.clients[id].ws.send(payload);
console.timeEnd();
```

takes up 0.1 - 0.2ms even though it's not sending much data! This seems exorbitantly slow. Is there any way to improve this with native WebSockets or do I have to use a different API?

Comment: Well even 1ms is 33 times per second, so 0.2ms is 165 times per second.  Are you getting your times mixed up here?   Also your time checking is not accurate anyway, your `send` is only timing how how to put that data into the buffer, how long it takes to send over the wire will be more.

Comment: To clarify, the problem here is that packing the data is by far the most expensive thing the server has to do. I know that it takes 30-100ms for the data to actually be delivered to the client, but the .1 to .2ms/ frame per client is really killing my performance.

Comment: Doing some testing on `ws`, that 0.1ms , 0.2ms seems to be the norm, no matter what options I use for `send`,  eg. `send(data, {binary:true, compress: false})` etc, don't seem to make any difference.  Looking at the code for `send`, https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/sender.js  I'm not really sure what's causing the issue, even using a callback makes no difference.   So one option is a SharedArrayBuffer & WebWorker,  personally I use a lot of WS small packets so it's something I might try myself.

Comment: Why send empty messages at all? Just skip the frame if you have no data.

Comment: Notice that [`console.time` is only "*accurate to the sub-millisecond*"](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-boron/api/console.html#console_console_time_label) but that's about what you measure. I'd recommend to build the message(s) first, then [measure how long it takes to send them to all clients](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66615742/1048572)

Comment: Is it slow when you send 1 packet, or is it only slow when you send 30 per second?

Comment: @Bergi  Using Node v18.17.0 It's way more accurate than just 0.1 0.2,  testing I can make an effect with dummy loops from 0.002 to say 0.020.. when increasing dummy loop 10 times larger.  Sure it not super accurate, but it should be giving better than 0.1 0.2 ms.  Also I think the OP's empty message it just a dummy OP, showing the slowdown on `send`.

Comment: @Evert  I'm getting `send` consistently take 0.1 - 0.2 ms per message, I've never noticed it before because I tend to debounce my messages.  But it has had me thinking, this 0.2ms delay on send is blocking NodeJS main event loop and of course in a heavy multi-user server this could be an issue, even if you use the `cb` variant.  I'm a tad surprised by this.

Comment: @Keith oops I didn't realise I read the nodejs docs of a totally outdated version…

Comment: I didn't realize this was on the server-side. Indeed this seems quite slow. I assume this is tested on your local machine and not some underpowered host?

Comment: But it does confuse me you're talking about native websockets. Does Node have websocket support now? i though this was usually provided by a library like `ws`

Comment: @Evert. Yeah, it's ws.  I posted a GitHub link to the send function earlier.  If I get chance I'll have a tinker and see what's blocking / holding for so long for something that should be mainly async.

Comment: For some closure, I just wanted to say that by migrating to uws.js and using the pub/sub methods things got 10x faster. Sending a payload over the wire was the time consuming part so packing multiple messages solved the performance concerns!

Comment: @Serum0017  I hope you mean uWebSockets.js,  as uws none maintained and known to have bugs.